# Export multiple bands from netCDF into GeoTIFFs

Tags: gdal, geotiff-tiff, netcdf, multi-band

I am working with a NetCDF file that has multiple subsets and each subset has multiple bands. I would like to take one subset and export each of the 28 bands into its own GeoTIFF. I thought that [gdal_translate](https://gdal.org/programs/gdal_translate.html) could do this via the `-sds` flag, which is described in GDAL documentation as "Copy all subdatasets of this file to individual output files. Use with formats like HDF that have subdatasets", however I guess this doesn't carry over to bands as well. This command:

```
gdal_translate -of GTiff -s_srs epsg:4326 -a_nodata = 0.0 -sds NETCDF:"oscar_vel2020_180.nc”:u temp.tif
```

generates the terminal prompt `>`.

How might I export each of the bands from the subset of the NetCDF file into its own GeoTIFF?

Answer (score 1):

First, I think you are getting the terminal prompt because you added a `=` in the commandline after `-a_nodata`. There should just be a space there.

Aside from that, you should be able to extract one of the bands from the subdataset "NETCDF:oscar_vel2020_180.nc:u" by using the `-b` switch in `gdal_translate`. Bands are numbered starting from 1 (see the [documentation](https://gdal.org/programs/gdal_translate.html) for more info).